# NPOI Linked Validations example doesn't work

Tags: c#, npoi

I'm working my way through the examples given on the NPOI github page and the Linked Validations example doesn't work - by that I mean, it's supposed to populate a dropdown list depending on a value in another dropdown list , the first dropdown is created ok but the second is not - anyone here tried it ? 
list

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, it does work it's just not immediately obvious you have to click on b1 to show thw dropdown ( slaps forehead )